# How to debug carbon-aggregator not aggregating series?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm trying to aggregate values from multiple metrics into one (obviously) but that's not happening and I'm desperately trying to figure out why. 
There's not much to go on though and I'm hoping get some more information on how to debug this.

Let's start with the environment:

```
Debian 9.11
graphite-carbon 0.9.15-1
```

The contents of my aggregation-rules.conf are:

```
app.all.values.<metric> (1800) = sum app.*.values.<metric>
```

My `storage-schemas.conf` has a section for these metrics:

```
[app]
pattern = ^app\.
retentions = 15m:15d,30m:30d,1h:180d,4h:2y,8h:4y,1d:8y
```

I do not have a section for `app` inside `storage-aggregation.conf`. It is my understanding that this isn't necessary?

The data is sent to graphite every 900 seconds (15 min) and I can see and query all the individual series just fine directly on graphite or from a grafana instance.

When I start a `graphite-aggregator` instance, I get these lines in the `aggregator.log` file:

```
07/10/2019 17:25:43 :: reading new aggregation rules from /etc/carbon/aggregation-rules.conf
07/10/2019 17:25:43 :: clearing aggregation buffers
```

But no aggregated metrics are ever created. I did have syntax errors in the beginning, but fixed them. Since then the aggregator process starts and runs successfully, it just never aggregates any metrics.

So how would I go about debugging this?

Comment: Hello, have you managed to get it work?

Comment: No, I haven't. I gave up on it and am using the `sum()` function in grafana.

Answer (score 0):

Do your metric names have only 4 nodes, or is  supposed to match across multiple nodes? You may need to use <> to match across more than one node/across dots.

For example, if you have a metric called "app.myapp.values.requests" it would match your existing rule, but "app.myapp.values.requests.count" wouldn't. However if you changed your rule to `app.*.values.<<metrics>>` it would match both examples.

Does that help?

Comment: They only have 4 nodes. Neither the `<>` nor the `*` are trying to span more than one node.